# How does one efficiently clean-up loose hair strands from one's back after washing hair in the shower? Is there a gadget designed to help with this?

Tags: bathroom, hair

I have shoulder-length to long hair whose loose strands cling to my wet back after I wash it in the shower, and even toweling off is sometimes not effective enough to remove the hardest-to-reach areas of my mid-back.  Is there any gadget that can help collect the loose strands that I can't reach?

Answer (score 1):

A much simpler and free way to remove those pesky hairs, is to wrap a towel around yourself so it is wrapped around your back, so that you are holding both ends of the towel in front of you, and the towel on your back. take one end of the towel that you are holding, and pull forward , let the other hand be pulled, but don't let go of either end of the towel. then repeat the motion with other hand so you feel the towel going side to side across your back. that should remove any stubborn hairs that are clinging on.

Answer (score 1):

I also have shoulder length hair and had a similar problem. I use a three step approach:

1. Direct the shower head directly at your back before you get out of
   the shower.
2. Towel off with careful attention to your back.
3. Use a blow drier to remove any remaining strands.

Answer (score 0):

A "lint roller" should do the trick. It's like a roll of adhesive tape, only the adhesive is on the outside of the roll.

[image: lint roller]

Once you're dry, you can hold the roller by the handle, reach over your shoulder, and roll the adhesive part across your upper and middle back. If you missed any part of your back, you can reach up under your armpit behind you, and roll the adhesive over the lower portion of your back.

In my experience, the adhesive doesn't bother my skin (unless I roll it over a hairy part like my forearms).

Answer (score 0):

I would use a cleaning brush, also called neck duster, after drying off. You've probably seen your hairdresser use them to clean off your neck before taking the cape off.

However, you might need to modify the handle for comfortable use on your own back.

http://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/NjAwWDgwMA==/z/c~AAAOSwstxU7Ic7/$_35.JPG

---

Another option would be a rubber lint roller. The hair strands stick to the roll due to its texture, so it works without adhesive. Just wash off with warm water.

http://www.promo-wholesale.com/Upfiles/Prod_r/Lint-Remover_20090637700.jpg

---

One more alternative is those old-fashioned lint brushes. They tend to be less abrasive as even many hair brushes to avoid damaging the fabric.

Answer (score 0):

I use a toothbrush. Works well on clothing too.